# how to put dwelling time in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

Hello i am a college student and have a little problem with my code. i want to give 3 seconds wait time in my code after a motorcycle get detected on the system, after that a sound came out. i try to manipulate the time but its not working. could anybody help with my code

```js
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pygame
import datetime as dt
from pygame import mixer
import time

#=============== Variable Mouse ==================#
drawing = False
point1 = ()
point2 = ()

drawingTwo = False
pointTwo_1 = ()
pointTwo_2 = ()
Mouse_count = False
#================================================#
def mouse_drawing(event, x, y, flags, params):
    global point1, point2, drawing
    global pointTwo_1, pointTwo_2, drawingTwo, Mouse_count

    #----------Mouse 1-------
    if Mouse_count == False:
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            if drawing is False:
                drawing = True
                point1 = (x, y)
            #else:
                #drawing = False

        elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
            if drawing is True:
                point2 = (x, y)
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
            drawing = False
            Mouse_count = True
            
    #----------Mouse 2-------#
    if Mouse_count == True:
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            if drawingTwo is False:
                drawingTwo = True
                pointTwo_1 = (x, y)
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
            if drawingTwo is True:
                pointTwo_2 = (x, y)
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
            if drawingTwo is True:
                drawingTwo = False
                Mouse_count = False
            
            
#================================================#
lastTime = dt.datetime.now()
currentTime = dt.datetime.now()

#Make Sound
pygame.mixer.init()


#create VideoCapture object and read from video file


cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test13.mp4')

cv2.namedWindow("Detecion motor")
cv2.setMouseCallback("Detecion motor", mouse_drawing)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    car_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascade11.xml')

    #============================== ROI One ============================#
    if point1 and point2:

        #Rectangle marker
        r = cv2.rectangle(frame, point1, point2, (100, 50, 200), 5)
        frame_ROI = frame[point1[1]:point2[1],point1[0]:point2[0]]

        #------------------Detect car ROI-------------------#
        if drawing is False:
            #convert video into gray scale of each frames
            ROI_grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(frame_ROI, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            #detect cars in the video
            cars_ROI = car_cascade.detectMultiScale(ROI_grayscale, 1.1, 3)
            if len(cars_ROI) > 0:
                if (currentTime-lastTime).seconds > 3:
                    lastTime = dt.dateTime.now()
                sound = mixer.Sound('sirine2.wav')
                sound.play()

            for (x,y,w,h) in cars_ROI:
                cv2.rectangle(frame_ROI,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
                currentTime = dt.datetime.now()
                #cv2.putText(frame_ROI, "Jumlah Motor : " + str(cars_ROI.shape[0]), (10,frame_ROI.shape[0] -25), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, 0.5,(0,255,0), 1)
       #-------------------------------------------------#
    #==================================================================#

    #============================== ROI Two ============================#

    #==================================================================#
    cv2.imshow("Detecion motor", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

i dont know i already try use time.sleep but its just make my system delay not solve my problem

Comment: What do you actually want to do?. Could you just explain more?

Comment: well i want to make a motorcylce detection using openCV. i make this code to detect a motorcycle that stop on the zebra cross. after the motorcycle get detected stop for 3 second in the zebra cross, i want a sound came out like a sirine or a warning sound that warn the bikers to step back.

Comment: I think time.sleep should work prefectly

Comment: when i use time.sleep the the moment motorcycle get detected, video get delayed too.what i want to give is just 3s interval when a motorcycle get detected stoping at zebra cross and then make the warning sound

Comment: or can you give an example how to use the time.sleep , maybe i dont use it right because im a new guy in this project

Comment: I added an answer check if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indention is wrong in your example this:

```
if (currentTime-lastTime).seconds > 3:
                    lastTime = dt.dateTime.now()
                sound = mixer.Sound('sirine2.wav')
                sound.play()
```

This is gonna play the sound every time a motorcycle is detected and your just reseting the lasttime variable. Instead do this :

```
if (currentTime-lastTime).seconds > 3:
                    lastTime = dt.dateTime.now()
                    sound = mixer.Sound('sirine2.wav')
                    sound.play()
```

Comment: i try it and its not working. its get a Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Skripsi/CarDetection-master/DeteksiMotor.py", line 88, in <module>
    lastTime = dt.dateTime.now()
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'dateTime'

Comment: It should be dt.datetime.now()